# Estimating dispersion parameters in GLMs

Tags: generalized-linear-model, dispersion

I've been working on implementing a [glm library](https://github.com/madrury/py-glm) in python for my students to use (for various reasons, the existing implementations are not sufficient).  My reference for the material is [Marlene Müller's paper](http://www.marlenemueller.de/publications/HandbookCS.pdf).

Müller gives two formulas for estimating the dispersion in a fit glm.  The first is in terms of the residual sum of squares:

$$ \hat a(\phi) = \frac{1}{n - p} \sum_i \frac{(y_i - \hat \mu_i)^2}{V(\hat \mu_i)} $$

And the second is in terms of the scaled deviance:

$$ \hat a(\phi) = \frac{D(y, \hat \mu)}{n - p} $$

At the moment, I've used the [second formula](https://github.com/madrury/py-glm/blob/master/glm.py#L220), but not for any very good reason.

So my question is: are there reasons to prefer one of these estimators over the other?  I would assume that they are both asymptotically correct, but is one better than the other in finite samples in any way?